Generation of D4 dihedral group by Symmetry operation notation in dynamical systems
I am reading in context of dynamical systems in case if it matters. It reads that $D_4$ action is generated by
$(x, y) \mapsto (-x, y)$
and
$(x, y) \mapsto (y, x)$ where $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$.
I understand that a 90 degree rotation and a reflection would generate the group, but why does the first symmetry operation represent 90 degree rotation?
Just some intuition on what x and y corresponds to and how it correspond to geometry would be great!

It does not. Both your operations are reflections. Together they do generate the group, though.
